# Three types of characteristics to achieve a goal

Tags: sutras, nirvana, buddha, desire

I have heard in a lot of sermons about how an individual achieve a goal. Even Buddha had the same type of characteristics. As far as I know they are

1. Determination
2. Consistency
3. Desire to see and end of the goal

My questions are,

1. Are these correct? If not what are they?
2. In which sutra can I find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is on the *four iddhipada*, the four mental factors of achieving a goal: chanda (intention), citta (thoughts), viriya (effort), wimansa (investigation). According to [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iddhipada) in wikipedia, there's a collection of discourses on this topic in Saṃyutta Nikāya called  [Iddhipāda Saṃyutta](https://suttacentral.net/sn51).

Answer (score 1):

These qualities are found in many *sutta*.

> *These are the four determinations: the determination
>   for discernment (wisdom), the determination for truth, the
>   determination for relinquishment, the determination for calm (peace)*.
>
> [MN 140](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.140.than.html)

~~~

> *'We will develop mindfulness...we will pursue it, hand it the reins and take it as a basis, give it a grounding, steady it, consolidate it
>   and undertake it well.' That is how you should train yourselves.*
>
> [SN 47.20](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn47/sn47.020.than.html)

~~~

> *And what is the faculty of persistence? There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, keeps his persistence aroused for
>   abandoning unskillful mental qualities and taking on skillful mental
>   qualities. He is steadfast, solid in his effort, not shirking his
>   duties with regard to skillful mental qualities. He generates desire,
>   endeavors, arouses persistence, upholds & exerts his intent for the
>   sake of the non-arising of evil, unskillful qualities that have not
>   yet arisen... for the sake of the abandoning of evil, unskillful
>   qualities that have arisen... for the sake of the arising of skillful
>   qualities that have not yet arisen... [and] for the maintenance,
>   non-confusion, increase, plenitude, development & culmination of
>   skillful qualities that have arisen. This is called the faculty of
>   persistence.*
>
> [SN 48.10](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.010.than.html)

~~~

> *Chanda mūlakā sabbe dhammā*
>
> *All dhamma-practises are rooted in 'chanda' (wholesome desire; zeal; devotion).*
>
> [AN 10.58](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.058.than.html)